# Change color in specific sections in sprite

Tags: unity, pixel-art

I have a game, where I would like to generate multiple enemies, just switching randomly their skin and clothes, colors. One way to do it, would be to break every position (each position composed by many sprites), like walk, idle, kick, in "layers" in Photoshop, and then import and organize the objects in a scene, connecting them by object parenting. I.e I have the player, then I add pants as child object and then I can control pants color and skin color separately. Theoretically it should work, however it would be a huge amount of work, if you think that I have almost 20 positions, each position is composed by at least 5 sprites. There is a better/easier way to do it? Maybe with 2D Shader?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the final look you want to achieve? Different visuals will sometimes demand different techniques — especially when it comes to shader effects.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe *will* work; we've done exactly that before. The key is to organize your asset creation flow. We used Illustrator/ Vector Smart Objects to build our layered files that were then "decolorized" before importing to Unity as sprites.

Another approach, especially if you are doing a pixel art style, would be to pre-process your sprite textures in Unity by making copies that replace key pixel colors with your enemy palette sets.